# Проблема при создании виртуального окружения

Tags: python

При попытке создать виртуальное окружение терминал возвращает python, и все.
Пытаюсь активировать ВО, выдает ошибку и пишет, что такой файл не найден.
Пробовал разные команды, не помогло

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Я так понимаю, у вас винда и вызывается тамошний странный дефолтный питон, это он обычно пишет в консоли `Python` и больше ничего. Скачайте и поставьте нормальный питон для начала. И нужно чтобы он в путях прописался.

Answer (score 1):

Можно создать к примеру, два разных способа:

```
virtualenv --python=python3 venv
```

или

```
python -m venv venv
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте создавать немного по другому, если речь идет о venv:

```
python3 -m venv your_project
source your_project/bin/activate
```

Первая команда - создает, а вторая - активирует.
Когда активация не нужна, введите

```
deactivate
```